# How to clear content which is not in active using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, zend-framework, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery UI tab for my project. Kindly check the html code

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="preload" class="load_cont" rel="tabs-1||general">General</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" class="load_cont" rel="tabs-2||admin_products">Admin Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3" class="load_cont" rel="tabs-3||admin_category">Admin Category</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4" class="load_cont" rel="tabs-4||admin_others">Others(Admin)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>
    <div id="tabs-3"></div>
    <div id="tabs-4"></div>
</div>
```

when I click a tab, I get the form using ajax, which works well. Check the js code below which is taken from phtml file,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        // Tabs
        $('#tabs').tabs();                        
        //hover states on the static widgets
        $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
        function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }             
    );

        $('.load_cont').click(function()
        {
            var groupname;
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var gnameArr = id.split('||');
            groupname = gnameArr[1];

            //alert(gnameArr[1]);
            var url = <?php echo BASE_URL; ?> + '/admin/settings/getqtips/gname/'+groupname;
            //alert(id);
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                url:url+'/math/'+Math.random(),
                data:'',
                success:function(response)
                {   
                    if(response.MSG == 'DONE')
                    {
                        $("#"+gnameArr[0]).html(response.TPL);
                        $('div#'+gnameArr[0]+' #gname').val(groupname);
                    }
                }
            });                   
        }    
    );              
    });
    $(function(){
        $('a#preload').click();
    })
</script>
```

My requirement is, when ever I click on respective tab, I need to clear the html inside other tab. That is, if I click on `tabs-2`, the content from other tabs (tabs-1, tabs-3, tabs-4) should be clear. This one saves my validation on zend.

Kindly advice on this.

Comment: do you have limited div with id tab or these are dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside your success function empty all other divs

```
$('div[id^="tabs-"]').each(function(){  //search for all divs which id starts with 'tabs-'
  if (this.id != gnameArr[0]) { //if this is not clicked one
    $(this).empty(); //clear its content
  }
});
```

or with [falsarella's tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803427/1064325)

```
$('.load_cont').click(function() {
  var clickedEl = $('#'+gnameArr[0]);
  ...
  success:functi...

  $('div[id^="tabs-"]').not(clickedEl).empty();

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set container elements with the same class, eg `.container`.

```
// Clear all container before you set the new one.
$('.container').html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this :

```
$('.load_cont').click(function(){
     $('.load_cont').not($(this)).each(function(i,el){
          $($(el).attr('href')).empty();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the divs that aren't the selected one, and clear them all:

```
$('#tabs > div:not(#' + gnameArr[0] + ')').empty();
```